# how to create ALTER TABLE statement that modifies the Groups table so the group name in each row has to be unique

Tags: sql, oracle

My code is

```
ALTER TABLE groups
MODIFY group_name UNIQUE;
```

But I am getting error and is not running
here is the error message :

> Error starting at line: 1 in command -
> ALTER TABLE groups
> MODIFY group_name UNIQUE
> Error report -
> ORA-02299: cannot validate (CS270103EX.SYS_C00287085) - duplicate keys found
> 02299. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - duplicate keys found"
> *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has duplicate key values.
> *Action:   Obvious

Comment: You will need to either delete the non-unique group_names first and then add the unique constraint (or add a `WITH NOCHECK` condition to apply your condition to future data only, not current data).

Comment: `*Action: Obvious` A little bit of humour from the error message writers. But it's funny because it's true: you get the error because your table has duplicate values in GROUP_NAME, so to fix it you need to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments, the issue is that you currently have duplicates which is preventing you from making your changes.

You can use a code block similar to the one below (may need to run it multiple times) to get all of the group names to be unique, then you should be able to apply your change.

```sql
BEGIN
    FOR i
        IN (SELECT GROUP_ID,
                      group_name
                   || ' '
                   || ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY GROUP_ID)    AS new_name
              FROM groups
             WHERE group_name IN (  SELECT group_name
                                      FROM groups
                                  GROUP BY group_name
                                    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1))
    LOOP
        UPDATE groups
           SET group_name = i.new_name
         WHERE GROUP_ID = i.GROUP_ID;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the constraint in a `DEFERRABLE`and `NOVALIDATE` state.

Lets simulate your case with this sample data

```
create table groups as
select 1 id, 1 group_name from dual union all
select 2 id, 1 group_name from dual;
```

The table contains duplicates in the column `group_name` but you can create the constraint and no now invalid data can be added

```
ALTER TABLE groups
MODIFY group_name UNIQUE DEFERRABLE ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Let's chek it

```
insert into groups (group_name) values (1) ;
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint (schema.SYS_C0011643) violated
```

Now you have all the time to clean up the old duplicates

```
delete from groups where id = 2;
commit;
```

And finaly you alter the constraint to the `VALIDATE` state, which meand, that the whole table is clean.

```
alter table groups modify constraint SYS_C0011643 enable validate;
```

Note this is prefered approach if you have a very volatile table where in the time you are clening anybody can insert new records.

If you are alone on the database, simple remove duplicates and add the constraint.